net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on Chrome browser for self-signed app on localhost
Need help in debugging an error in dev env.
Things were working fine but suddenly yesterday my app stopped rendering in Chrome
Following calls are erroring out:
GET https://my-app.local:4042/app/main.tsx net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED localization:70
GET https://my-app.local:4042/@vite/client net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED localization:64
GET https://my-app.local:4042/@react-refresh net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED localization:62

Things are working fine in Firefox. cURL is able to resolve the above requests.
I suspect it to be a self-signed certificate issue in Chrome.
I have enabled chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost but still doesn't work.
I have tried removing-adding the self-signed cert, going back in git history and clearing node_modules, alas, with no luck.
I installed the Canary version of the Chrome and it worked for 15 mins but then started erroring out on it as well. Certificate hasn't expired and is in use for months.
I have been working on this web app for last 6 months and things were working fine.
Off late team had bumped up the node and vite version. Things were working fine even after the upgrade.
Others in the team don't seem to have an issue(atleast till now).
No errors are reported in node and backend server logs.

There is something wrong with my network config. I need to look into it.
For now, I could make it work by exposing the vite server over the local network using yarn dev --host
